# Integrating $\int (x+1)^2 dx$ two ways gives different results: $\frac13 x^3+x^2+x$ vs $\frac13 x^3+x^2+x+\frac13$. Why?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to compute $$\int (x+1)^2 \, dx~,$$ which is a really easy function to integrate.

But the thing is that I write the function as $x^2 +2x+1$ and the result I got was $\frac{x^3}{3} +x^2 +x$.

But then I tried to integrate it using substitution; I called $u=x+1$, so the function I had to integrate was $$\int (u)^2 \, du~,$$ and the result is $\frac{u^3}{3}$ and then $\frac{(x+1)^3}{3}$, which is equal to $\frac{x^3}{3} +x^2 +x+\frac{1}{3}$ and that's different from the previous result!

Comment: Don't forget "$+C$"!

Comment: Another example using integration by parts:
$$
\int \frac1x \, dx
= \int 1 \cdot \frac1x \, dx
= x \cdot \frac1x - \int x \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, dx
= 1 + \int \frac1x \, dx
$$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that when evaluating an indefinite integral, you have an infinite family of solutions.  Since you lose constant factors when differentiating, both functions are solutions.  That's why we add a "$+C$" to our solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING while dealing with INDEFINITE INTEGRALS!!**

When you solve some indefinite indefinite integral you should always add a constant in your final result (why?). Remember that indefinite integral is nothing but anti-derivative. Therefore, whenever you integrate you miss a constant which disappears because the derivative of constant is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution is the way to solve your integral and the constant is OK. because it drops under differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Both the ways actually give the same answer. The $~\frac{1}{3}~$ part is a constant which can be written as '$~C~$' , which is just the constant part of indefinite integration (which sometimes people don't write). If you put limit on integration e.g.,: $~0\le x\le 1~$.

You'll see that both the approaches yield the same answer.

**Note:** When you substitute $~x+1~$ with $~u~$, the limit changes from $~(0, 1)~$  to $~(1, 2)~$.

Answer (score 0):

You have, effectively, just modified the arbitrary constant that is associated with each (here only one) connected component of the integrand's domain. Note that the term $\frac{1}{3}$ is a constant, containing no occurrences of $x$.

The "true" answer to an indefinite integration problem

$$\int f(x)\ dx$$

where $\mathrm{dom}(f)$ is connected, is the *set* of functions

$$\{ x \mapsto [F(x) + C] : C \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

for any function $F$ such that $F' = f$: that is, all those whose values are offset from some representative by a constant shift. Note that if you take either $x \mapsto \frac{1}{3} x^3 + x^2 + x$ or $x \mapsto \frac{1}{3} x^3 + x^2 + x + \frac{1}{3}$ as being $F$, the other will differ from it by a constant shift $C$ only (respectively $\frac{1}{3}$ and $-\frac{1}{3}$), hence both belong to this set and, moreover (considering *all* possible $C$) the set is uniquely and hence well-defined.